# Fractional epoch in deep learning using H2O

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, h2o

I understand the concept of epoch as
epoch = one forward pass and one backward pass of all the training examples, in the neural network terminology. So i assume it must be an integer, however why in some instances as the code below having a fractional epoch #?

```
dlmodel <- h2o.deeplearning(
  x=predictors,
  y="bin_response", 
  training_frame=train,
  hidden=c(10,10),
  epochs=0.1
)
```

The h2o document says
epochs: The number of passes or over the training dataset (can be fractional). It is recommended
to start with lower values for initial grid searches. The value can be modified during checkpoint
restarts and allows continuation of selected models. Default is 10.

But i still don't understand what fractional # can do here.

Comment: Thank you Frans, then why don't i just divide the data equally into 10 batches, and running 1 batch (which is 1/10 of full data) for 1 full epoch?

Comment: While I was also thinking about my question earlier, could it be possible that 0.1 means 1/10 of the full training cycle? i.e. a full cycle contains many earning processes through connections between nodes, especially with multi hidden layers. so instead of having all nodes connecting to each other for the full learning, only 1/10 of the connections were randomly selected for the learning. A short learning process for a quick result. Would this understanding make sense?

Comment: Selecting connections at random sounds more like dropout than a fractional epoch. It is not the connections that are excluded, but the input: the observations.

Answer (score 2):

In an **epoch**, all observations have made one backward and forward pass through the network. Since this can be too memory-intensive, a **mini-batch** can be used to calculate the gradient, which is a fraction of the total data. The epoch is then split into several mini-batches. One epoch *still* uses all data, but is simply split into several parts to save memory.

You will eventually want to run at least one epoch and use all training data available, but this may be too computationally intensive for some simple trial-and-error, so you may want to consider running less than a full epoch in this case. Hence the fractional epoch.